# How much mechanical energy (power) is converted to electrical energy (power) to have output voltage (no load connected)?

Tags: generator

greeting .

How much mechanical energy (power) is converted to electrical potential to have output voltage (no load connected)?

Comment: Zero. As told to you in physics class during the laws of thermodynamics session.

Comment: In order for voltage to be produced, the electrical generator must have a magnetic field. If that field is produced electrically, the required power must be either converted from mechanical power or supplied from some other generator. That is a small percentage of the capacity of the generator. Additional mechanical power is required to keep the system in motion, but that power is converted to heat rather than electrical power.

Answer (score 2):

Zero.

Think of it like a fully charged battery with out any load attached. The chemical energy in battery is limited and can be converted into a definite amount of electrical energy. But when no loads are connected, how much chemical energy is converted to electrical energy? **None**.

Similarly, when no loads are attached to a generator, no mechanical energy is being converted to electrical energy. Efficiency of the generator is zero. Whatever mechanical energy is being consumed is being spent to overcome friction, windage and intertia.